# how to get zabbix item values in two different time for trigger?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, zabbix

For monitoring some database servers parameters (**NOT ZABBIX self**), In zabbix I need to create a trigger for checking an item value at every 15 minute and run if the last retrieve value is increase or decrease from now retrieve value.

How to create that trigger?

Comment: Here is my current understanding of your question. You already have database monitoring items set up and they are checked every 15 minutes. The only thing you need help with is creating a trigger that would notify you when the last value differs from a previous value or differs by a certain amount. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @asaveljevs, I edited my question. This triggers is needed for other hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit does not answer my question. Do I understand correctly that you already have items set up and the only thing you need help with is the trigger? The trigger should notify you if the item's value has changed?

Comment: @asaveljevs, YES!

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to see whether the last value differs from the previous value, you should use the `diff()` function, like so:

```
{host:item.diff()} = 1
```

If you wish to see whether the last value differs from the previous value by a certain amount, you should use the `change()` function, like so:

```
{host:item.change()} < -100 | {host:item.change()} > 100
```

If you wish to construct more complicated expressions, you might wish to consider using `prev()` and `last()` functions to explicitly refer to the last two values. For instance, the `diff()` example above can be replaced with:

```
{host:item.prev()} # {host:item.last()}
```

You probably also want the trigger to generate multiple successive PROBLEM events by selecting the checkbox on the right of "Multiple PROBLEM events generation". In that case, if an item goes from 0 to 150 to 300, you will be notified on both changes. Otherwise, you will only be notified on the first change.

Also see [official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) for a complete list of available trigger functions.

Comment: +1 Thank you, although your answer was not my exact answer, but it was very very useful, so i used it and solved my problem.